# Filtering on foreign key relationship - Django

Tags: django, filtering, django-queryset

I want to find the number of `articles` for which a specific user has created `articlehistory` records.
The models for that look like this:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    """The basic entity of this app.)"""
    documentID = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1000)
    cowcode = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    pubdate = models.DateField(default=datetime.datetime.today)
    headline = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=1500)
    source = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=5000)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True, max_length=1000000)
    assignments = models.ManyToManyField(Assignment)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['pubdate']

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.headline

class ArticleHistory(models.Model):
    """(Modelname description)"""
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='Article History')
    coder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Article History')
    last_updated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.last_updated
```

The way I'm trying to do this at the moment is like this:

```
assignment.finished_articles = Article.objects.filter(cowcode=country).filter(pubdate__range=(start_date,end_date), articlehistory__coder=request.user.id).count()
```

This doesn't work, however and exhibits another weird behaviour:
I try to do this:

```
for assignment in assignments:
    country = assignment.country.cowcode
    start_date = assignment.start_date
    end_date = assignment.end_date
    articles = Article.objects.filter(cowcode=country).filter(pubdate__range=(start_date,end_date)).select_related()
    assignment.article_num = articles.count()
    #assignment.finished_articles = Article.objects.filter(cowcode=country).filter(pubdate__range=(start_date,end_date), articlehistory__coder=request.user.id).count()
```

This works fine, unless I try to include `finished_articles`, then `article_num` gets shortened to one result.

It would be really great if anyone has a pointer to who to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of reverse relation of ForeignKey created by parameter related_name:

1. Rename attribute related name to `"article_history_set"`.
2. Now, it gives you easy pointer: `user.article_history_set` is a set of Article History objects where coder is set to this user.
3. Then you can find which article it is related to by doing `article_history.article`.
4. At the end, you have to get rid of repetition and get length of that list.

Here you have more about related_name attribute: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_name

Comment: Thanks! By 1. you mean change `coder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='Article History')` to `coder = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='article_history_set')`, right?

Comment: Actually, `related_name="whatever_you_want_but_without_spaces"`. This string will be used as a name of the User's attribute: `user.whatever_you_want_but_without_spaces`. So, I don't think so that name with spaces will work ;)